# React native VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I am making some app with react native. everything are working perfectly but i got React native VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain warning message when i put Flatlist into Scroll View Or Content (Nativebase). here is my code

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <Content>
        <SliderBox
            images={this.state.hotel_photo}
            sliderBoxHeight={200} 
        />
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.hotel_rooms}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
            numColumns={2}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                return (
                    <View>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemsa}>
                            <Image source={{uri:item.photo}}
                                style={styles.itemsimg} />
                            <Text style={{textAlign:'center',fontSize:16, }}>{item.name}</Text>
                            <Text style={{fontSize:16,textAlign:'center'}}>${item.price}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                )
            }}
            
        />
</View>
```

Comment: I dont understand your question. The warning is telling you to not nest them. You will get the warning if you nest them. Do you want to quiet the warning or know how to rewrite your code to need the nesting? Scrolls within scrolls are difficult UX because you can't know which scroll you're actually scrolling without visual cues. Please add what you are trying to accomplish to get answers.

Comment: @zero298 Thank you for comment. actually my question is i got VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain warning message when i trying use Flatlist. is my flatlist are wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a try by **removing the Content Component** and **add the SliderView component in the flatlist header component** to show the imageView above the flatlist and allow it to scroll

for **example**:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <FlatList
        data={this.state.hotel_rooms}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        numColumns={2}
        ListHeaderComponent={
            <SliderBox
                images={this.state.hotel_photo}
                sliderBoxHeight={200} 
            />
        }
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
            return (
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemsa}>
                        <Image source={{uri:item.photo}}
                            style={styles.itemsimg} />
                        <Text style={{textAlign:'center',fontSize:16, }}>{item.name}</Text>
                        <Text style={{fontSize:16,textAlign:'center'}}>${item.price}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            )
        }}
        
    />
</View>
```